# Laravel - Obtener BLOB en respuesta Json u otro

Tags: laravel, blob

Estoy obteniendo información especifica de un `id`, el detalle es qué viene con columnas `blob`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi respuesta al intentar 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi controlador:

```
if(ctype_digit($id) == false)
   return redirect('/')->with('error', 'Id invalido');
$content = Contenido::find($id);
return $content;
```

**¿Que me recomiendan para estos casos?**

Comment: Si es un JSON pienso no deberías obtener el archivo como tal sino que solamente sea su nombre

Comment: entiendo, por ello puse `u otro` en si busco la forma de traer ese archivo.

Comment: intentaste `return response()->json($content->file);`?